# How can I make a counter keep increasing to a certain number on a specified date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a counter for my website that increases to a number, but reaches that number after a year.

For example, the counter starts at 0 and its target number is 35340340, so the counter should reach that number after one year has passed.

I've been trying and I can create an animated counter that takes 31,556,900,000 milliseconds to reach its target number, but it resets to 0 every time I load the page, so I don't know if it is possible to indicate a date as it is done with a downtimecounter, but do it with a counter that goes up and is not based on seconds and minutes.

Comment: You must calculate passed time from specific date

Comment: The counter you've created is local to your website, and will reset every time you load the page. To get the real Date Time, you will have to have a backend from which you can get the start and end date and with those values you can calculate the rate at which your counter should increase / decrease.

Comment: Is this counting seconds, minutes, or some other unit time? Should it count from a hard-coded date/time, or can different visitors have different counters? Is that local time, or should the count be identical for everyone regardless of their time zone? What should happen on the web page when the counter reaches the target number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know when you set the counter

So you can do this calculation each time you load

NOTE you need to consider timezones if it is important that the number is reached at a specific time

```js
const targetNumber = 35340340;
const speed = 100; // milliseconds
const startDate = new Date(2021,11,16,15,0,0,0); // normalise at 15:00 - here yesterday
const aYearLater = new Date(startDate.getFullYear()+1,startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate(),15,0,0,0); 
const diffMS = aYearLater.getTime() - startDate.getTime(); // 365 or 366 in ms
const ticksPerMS = targetNumber/diffMS;
// console.log(ticksPerMS); 
const now = new Date();
const diffFromStart = now.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
let counterNow = (diffFromStart*ticksPerMS)
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
setInterval(function() {
  counter.innerText = (counterNow += (ticksPerMS*speed)).toFixed(2)
},speed)
```

```html
<span id="counter"></span>
```

Update from your comment

```js
const initialNumber = 99.990867579909;
const targetFinal = 100.000000000000;
const targetNumber = targetFinal - initialNumber;


const speed = 100; // milliseconds
const startDate = new Date(2021, 11, 16, 15, 0, 0, 0); // normalise at 15:00 - here yesterday
const aYearLater = new Date(startDate.getFullYear() + 1, startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate(), 15, 0, 0, 0);
const diffMS = aYearLater.getTime() - startDate.getTime(); // 365 or 366 in ms
const ticksPerMS = targetNumber / diffMS;
// console.log(ticksPerMS); 
const now = new Date();
const diffFromStart = now.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
let counterNow = (diffFromStart * ticksPerMS)
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let tId = setInterval(function() {
  counter.innerText = (counterNow += (ticksPerMS * speed)).toFixed(12)
  if (counterNow >= targetFinal) clearInterval(tId);
}, speed)
```

```html
<span id="counter"></span>
```

Comment: Please note, visitors in different time zones will see a different count. That is because the count started at 15:00 in their local time.

Comment: That would be a difference of 70 ticks per hour's difference which is a 0.01‱, or so? I guess I do not need to normalise then

Comment: OP did not mention at what time of the day the counter should reach the number

Comment: Just pointing out that US site visitors will reach the target hours after European users do. That's OK when you're counting towards a new year's celebration, but not when you're counting towards a lunar eclipse. Should make that clear to people willing to copy/paste a code snippet, blindly assuming it will fit their use case.

Comment: And what if I want to use decimals?

Comment: And what if I don't want the counter to start at 0?
I create this:

   const initialNumber = 99.990867579909;
   const targetFinal = 100.000000000000;

And change the constant targetNumber to this:

   const targetNumber = targetFinal - initialNumber;

And then at the end add and change this:

   let counterNow = diffFromStart * ticksPerMS;
   let showNumber = (counterNow + initialNumber)
   const counter = document.getElementById ("counter");

   setInterval (function () {
   counter.innerText = (showNumber + =
   (ticksPerMS * speed)). toFixed (12)
   }, speed)
It's okay?

Comment: Possibly. see update